# Calculation puzzle 004

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

20 ~ 32 = 100

22 ~ 19 = 25

81 ~ 50 = 81

24 ~ 22 = ?

Possible answers: 225, 196, 121, 625 or 400.

I saw [this question](https://14773644510176710490.googlegroups.com/attach/451f4163f3c03/IMG_3453.jpg?part=0.1&view=1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGj5h-1K2dEYoMyI6NhdCqTSz3PqDFOAxV1BDpYOSCgl6jA8JMqfBOeQYdmaZotdf3l8dFFncatjQTCgGKWgX4Z9dcPaLIQR-y1_Uzr6jGp7730598) on the internet, these question types are YÖS exam questions and as seen from the picture I think it belongs to [YÖS questions book by Kuark publications](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=kuark%20yay%C4%B1nlar%C4%B1%20y%C3%B6s). I tried to solve it myself but couldn't. Obviously, the resulting numbers are related to the squares, but squares of what; difference between each number, or digits, or summation of them, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where I got this question [got a solution now](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tmoz/kV-7hibzXR8).

> $$2^0+3^2=10^2=100$$
>  $$2^2+1^9=5^2=25$$
>  $$8^1+5^0=9^2=81$$
>  $$2^4+2^2=20^2=400$$

Comment: There are actually an infinite number of solutions to your puzzle, but I'm glad you found a solution you're satisfied with.